# No Errors but No Results from ToList()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created my connection string and it seems to be connecting without error.  I am simply trying to output the various `ID`s, but it's acting like there's nothing there!

The table is full of records...  It doesn't output any error, either.  How can I even debug something like this?

Model:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class Directory
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public bool DELETED { get; set; }
        public Guid CREATED_BY { get; set; }
        public DateTime DATE_ENTERED { get; set; }
        public Guid MODIFIED_USER_ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime DATE_MODIFIED { get; set; }
        public Guid USER_ID { get; set; }
        public Guid BRANCH_ID { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Directory> Directories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.Directory> 

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
           @item.ID
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private Models.MyDbContext db = new Models.MyDbContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";
            return View(db.Directories.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is pointing at the correct database and not one with an empty Directories table?

Comment: Your `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)` doesn't make sense. Are you sure you're passing the right model to the template?

Comment: @JeffSiver I am not sure how to be sure, but I assume it would complain if there was some sort of error.

Comment: @CAbbott As CuddleBear suggested, I have replaced it with `item.ID` but still, no errors and no results.  Good idea, though.

Comment: I'm not saying it is an error; I'm thinking you are getting no data displayed because there is no data to display (the Directories table has no rows).

Comment: I am looking at the directories table and it has 985 rows in it.  Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: how many entries are in Directories? can you do db.Directories.Count ?

Comment: Maybe I don't know what I'm talking about, but where are you populating your `db` object? Maybe I don't know anything about `Dbset`s, `Directories` or `DbContext`s; but I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: @KyleC I added `ViewBag.Count = db.Directories.Count();` to my controller and `ViewBag.Count = @ViewBag.Count` to my view but it just outputs `ViewBag.Count = `.

Comment: Okay, guys, thanks for your help.  I figured it out.  I was using the wrong table name to start with, but then I also needed to add `Database.SetInitializer<Models.MyDbContext>(null);` to my global.asax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all for your help.  I figured it out.  I was using the wrong table name to start with, but then I also needed to add `Database.SetInitializer<Models.MyDbContext>(null);` to my global.asax...

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the Directory DbSet in the Constructor of your DbContext.

```
Directories = Set<Directory>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem just now cause i forgot to add connectionString in my web.config file.
So if the above answers dont help check that also.